# How to have two different backgrounds for a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, statelistdrawable

I have a linear layout and there is an onClickListener implemented on it.
Now I want that when it is clicked its background color to white is changed and remains that way until something else is clicked. When something else is clicked I want it to have transparent background
How to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two drawable images in your drawable folder. And when it is clicked, you can change the background of the layout.
Following code changes the background:

```
 LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    layout.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_name));
```

Comment: how can I do this using xml in state list drawable. Idon't have separate images. I just want to change the background

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also just use a selector as background. You can probably take advantage of the 'selected' or 'focused' states to toggle the background between transparent and white. It'll look something like:

```
<LinearLayout
...
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_selector"
...
</LinearLayout>
```

And then `bg_list_selector.xml` in your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <!-- or -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Have a play with the StateListDrawable's different options, I'd say.

Comment: I have tried this & it does work, but only temporarily. I mean the background changes when it is clicked but not permanently.

Comment: Define 'permanently'. My guess is that the 'selected' state is more interesting in your case, but it does require you to manually set a View's state. For example, in [`onListItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29), do something like `v.setSelected(true)`.